# How to prove that a homomorphism $\pi$ is a representation of SU(2)?

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have been struggling with a exercise. Here is the statement of the problem:

Given the group of matrixes SU(2) (special unitary group) having a natural action on $\mathbb{C}^2$ as:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    z & w\\
    -w^* & z^*
    \end{pmatrix}\, 
\begin{pmatrix}
    a\\
    b
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    za + wb\\
    -w^*a + z^*b
    \end{pmatrix},
$$

where $z,w,a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Consider the following homomorphism $\pi : SU(2) \rightarrow GL(4,\mathbb{C})$ such that:

$$
\pi \begin{pmatrix}
    z & w\\
    -w^* & z^*
    \end{pmatrix}\, 
\begin{pmatrix}
    a\\
    b
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    z^2& zw & zw & w^2\\
    -zw^*& zz^* & -ww^* & wz^*\\
    -zw^*& -ww^* & zz^* & wz^*\\
    w^{*2}& -wz^* & -wz^* & z^{*2}\\
    \end{pmatrix},
$$

where $GL(4,\mathbb{C})$ is the group of complex and invertible matrixes $4\times 4$. Show that $\pi$ is a representation of SU(2).

I am pretty confused about this since in many books I have read so far about this topic, it always starts by defining this homeomorphism and directly say that the homeomorphism ($\pi$ in this case) is a representation of the given Lie group. To show my point I have attached a definition of one of the many books I have been reading in order to tackle this problem. Because I am asked to prove what many definitions take for granted, or am I missing something here?

[image]

I would appreciate any help about how to resolve this problem, such as better explained bibliography for this kind of representations, some hints or well developed answers.
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: What you have described is *not* an action of $SU(2)$ on $\Bbb C^2$. In order to be an action, the action of an element of $SU(2)$ on an element of $\Bbb C^2$ should be another element of $\Bbb C^2$, not a $2\times2$ matrix.

Comment: That is how it is described in my exercise...

Comment: Not my fault. I am not the person who wrote it.

Comment: Then, how should I rephrase it? Thanks a lot for the correction

Comment: I suspect that what you meant was$$\begin{bmatrix}z&w\\-\overline w&\overline z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}za+wb\\-\overline wa+\overline zb\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You are completely right, I have written it wrongly. My bad!!! So, could you please give me some indications on how to tackle this problem? Thanks a lot again!!!

Comment: I also suspect that, when you wrote$$\pi\begin{pmatrix}
    z & w\\
    -w^* & z^*
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    a\\
    b
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    z^2& zw & zw & w^2\\
    -zw^*& zz^* & -ww^* & wz^*\\
    -zw^*& -ww^* & zz^* & wz^*\\
    w^{*2}& -wz^* & -wz^* & z^{*2}\\
    \end{pmatrix},
$$that $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ should not be there.

Comment: Do not write homeomorphism when you mean homomorphism.

Comment: Being a homomorphism means $\pi(AB) = \pi(A)\pi(B)$ for all $A$ and $B$ in ${\rm SU}(2)$. If other books called that $\pi$ a representation, that means they *skipped* the verification of the homomorphism property: you still should check it. Claiming a formula is a homomorphism does not prove it is one. If I called $f(x) = 7+2x$ a homomorphism from $\mathbf R$ to itself, would you accept that without checking it yourself?